# Squashing commits while merging a branch from a separate fork

Tags: git, branch, git-fork, squash

How do I merge a branch from a fork into the current `master` while simultaneously squashing the commits, without asking the fork maintainer to do it for me?

For example, if my project is hosted at `acme/helloworld:master` and the fork is at `coyote/helloworld:patch`, and the `patch` branch has 10 extra commits, how do I merge `coyote/helloworld:patch` into `acme/helloworld:master` in one commit without any intervention from the owner of the fork?

Comment: `git checkout master;git merge patch --squash;git commit` or `git checkout -b patch_in_one;git reset HEAD~10 --soft;git commit;git checkout master;git merge patch_in_one`

Comment: @ElpieKay I was searching for a way to merge in a branch and squash all commits into one for two hours, and your comment nailed it. You should definitely make this into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to merge in only one commit,

there are a couple of ways you can perform this. For instance, you can do this using a feature called **git rebase -i**

using rebase will open an interactive shell which will help you merge a number of commits into a single commit and also to move the head of the fork branch to the latest commit in the master branch. For example , in your case, you can use the following commands.

git checkout coyote/helloworld:patch ;

This will open a text editor listing all of the commits that are about to be moved

The content will look like below,

pick 33d5b7a Message for commit #1

pick 9480b3d Message for commit #2

pick 5c67e61 Message for commit #3

This listing defines exactly what the branch will look like after the rebase is performed. By changing the pick command and/or re-ordering the entries, you can make the branch’s history look like whatever you want. For example, if the 2nd commit fixes a small problem in the 1st commit, you can condense them into a single commit with the fixup command like below,

pick 33d5b7a Message for commit #1

fixup 9480b3d Message for commit #2

pick 5c67e61 Message for commit #3

When you save and close the file, Git will perform the rebase according to your instructions.

Hence, it will rebase and also combine the commits in a single commit.

Comment: Please validate this and rank if satisfactory